# Bootstrap progress bar with angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I using bootstrap to show the progress bar. To change the value in the progress bar I am using Angular 2 Attribute Binding.

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" [attr.aria-valuenow]="progress" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax ="100" 
  style="min-width: 2em;" [style.width]="(progress/100)*100 + '%'">
   {{progress}}%
  </div>
```

variable progress will be increasing when I upload a file and I am able to see the values in console log.

```
this.service.progress.subscribe(
data => {
    console.log('progress = '+data);
    this.progress = data;
    console.log(this.progress) ;
  });
```

Problem: The progress bar is showing 0 and then 100 once the upload is complete it is not progressing or showing in between values.please suggest.

Comment: could you recreate your problem on plunker ?

Comment: My code is as in plunker and the uplading is done is shown in the below tutorial.
https://plnkr.co/edit/Z46QwU?p=preview
Uploading : https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/upload-files-to-node-js-using-angular-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in the code. As the uploaded file size is very low it is quickly uploading. When i upload a bigger file it is working as expected.